# Avoid data duplication in child class mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I'm working on an windows phone app where I'm using MVVM pattern with it. In short, I've got a list which is binded to class. This class contains an observable collection which store information for each individual rows.

Is there a way to avoid duplicating data in a child class when only one instance of the specific data is required to be set in a parent class. Think of the following scenario:

Grid
  - TableName
  - Rows

As mentioned, the rows property is an Observable Collection i.e. ObservableCollection where the row is a class made up of numerous properties such as Id, Code, Name, etc...

This observable collection is binded to a list and each row's viewmodel has a action binded to an ICommand to it so that when it is tapped, it will trigger an event and I will be able to redirect to another page but I'll be able to use the row's information i.e. Id, Code, etc...

The problem is that I need access to the TableName and while I could include it as one of the row's class property, it seems pointless as this will be the same value over and over again.

What is the proper way to design this? Is there a specific pattern that applies to this scenario or is just a case of duplicating the data in each of the rows... It just doesn't feel right!

Thanks.

T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create the `ICommand` in the `TableNameVM` and it gets passed to each child `RowVM` to expose as a simple property. If the implementation of the command inside `TableNameVM` needs the Row, then just pass it as the command parameter.

You could even forego adding it the `RowVM`, and just use `RelativeSource` on the row binding to bind to the TableName instead. However, I must admit I dislike this kind of short cutting in the view.

Something like this:

```
public class TableNameVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ICommand myCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<RowVM> Rows { get; set; }

    public TableNameVM()
    {
        this.myCommand = new DelegateCommand<RowVM>(ExecuteMyCommand);

        //create 10 rows
        for(int n = 1; n < 10; n++)
            this.Rows.Add(new RowVM(this.myCommand));
    }

    private void ExecuteMyCommand(RowVM row)
    {
        //do whatever
    }
}

public class RowVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

    public RowVM(ICommand myCommand)
    {
        this.MyCommand = myCommand;
    }
}
```

Your Row button to fire the command would look something like:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParam="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: Hi, sorry still learning mvvm. I understand what you mean by adding the ICommand at the TableNameVM but what do you mean by "it gets passed to each child RowVM to expose as a simple property." Can you explain with a basic sample code? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that. I see what you mean now! :) ... Is that ok practise to do it like this?

Comment: I see no reason why not. I often do similar and have found it nice and clean.

Comment: Great! It worked! It took me a while longer as my description above was very basic, but I had additional layer creating a more complex hierarchy between each object, but eventually I got there :). Also had to change my DelegateCommand to use a generic instead of an object which is far better! Learned two things in one post!! Always a good thing. Thanks again!